# Trying to make a redirect page

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am creating a new user and saving it in my DB as shown below:

```
const user= new User({
    username: userId,
    password: pass,
    nameOfUser: user_name,
    emailOfUser: user_email
);
user.save();

res.redirect("/redirectpage");
setTimeout(function(){
    res.redirect("/");
},5000);
```

After saving the user I am trying to create a countdown redirect page. It looks something like:

[image]

After this, counter (of 5 seconds) reaches 0, I intend to redirect the user to the login page which is the home route. I implemented this through setTimeout. But unfortunately my app crashes giving the following errors:
(** Note: If i comment out res.redirect("/redirectpage"), no errors are shown)

[image]

Comment: Once you send a result to the user from Express, you can't send anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code tries to redirect the user twice. First to `/redirectpage` and then again to `/`. You can't do this, because calling `res.redirect()` the first time finishes the request, so you can't send any more data like a second redirect. You can fix this by moving the redirect code to the client side javascript. This code should work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.replace("[full redirect url]");
}, 5000);
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/9114802) to learn more about redirecting from the client-side.